# WEBPACK - How to get individual css files from a folder

Tags: javascript, css, node.js, webpack, sass

I have a problem and I don't know if is possible to solve it.
In my project I have two folders: **layout** and **blocks**

```
layout
|__header.scss
|__footer.scss
|__sidebar.scss

blocks
|__ block1.scss
|__ block2.scss
|__ block3.scss
```

What I try to get is a single file from the layout folder (example: `layout.min.css`) and individual files for blocks (example: `block1.min.css`, `block2.min.css`, `block3.min.css`).

Is it possible?

Comment: yes, it is possible

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use below configurations to generate multiple Css bundles for each folder

```
const path = require("path");
const ExtractTextWebpackPlugin = require("extract-text-webpack-plugin");

const layoutCss = new ExtractTextWebpackPlugin("layout.css");
const blockCss = new ExtractTextWebpackPlugin("blocks.css");

module.exports = {
  entry: "./src/index.js",

  output: {
    filename: "[name].js",
    path: path.resolve(path.join(__dirname, "./dist")),
  },

  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /layout\/.*\.scss$/,
        use: layoutCss.extract({
          use: "css-loader",
        }),
      },
      {
        test: /block\/.*\.scss$/,
        use: blockCss.extract({
          use: "css-loader",
        }),
      },
    ],
  },

  plugins: [layoutCss, blockCss],
};
```

Comment: Hi Shubham Sharma, thank you very much, a little clarification: Extract Text Plugin is deprecated, recommend using this
 https://github.com/webpack-contrib/mini-css-extract-plugin